# Do recursion and counting numbers at the same time in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

If I had a known list `A :: [Int]`, and wanted to get a new list `B = newList A` with `newList` defined as the following:

```
newList :: [Int] -> [Int]
newList [] = []
newList (a:as) | a==0      = f(a) : newList (as)
               | a==1      = g(a) : newList (as)
               | otherwise = h(a) : newList (as)
```

where `f, g, h :: Int -> Int` are unimportant functions.

Other than `B`, I also wanted to know how many `0, 1` are there in `A` respectively.

But since when producing `B` recursively, it has already checked whether `a== (0 or 1)` for each elements in `A`, so it's a redundancy to check it again separably.

Is it possible to get `B` but at the same time get how many `0, 1` are there in `A` with checking only once?

Comment: first you can exchange `f(a)` with the value `f 0` and `g(a)` with the value `g 1`here - and then yes it is possible, for example you can use `foldr` to do so - maybe you'll want to have a look at it before we spoil it?

Comment: hint: the idea is to fold up the list into a tuple `(na,nb,xs)` where `na` is the number of *seen* `a`s,  `nb` is the same for `b`s and `xs` is the mapped list you did here with `map h` (look for a way to express `map` using `foldr` first - additional hint: use `(:)` and `[]` ;)

Comment: `mapAccumR` can also be of help, since it combines a fold with a map.

Comment: @chi, why not `mapAccumL`?

Comment: @user3237465 because the above looks like a `foldr`-style recursion.

Comment: @chi, it's the mapping part is `foldr`-style recursion — that part both the `mapAccum`s have, since both are defined in terms of `traverse`. However it seems more natural to sum `Int`s from left to right.

Comment: I think I have solved it, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer you are looking for, but there is a nice abstract structure behind your function, so I'll leave it here:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Functor
import Data.Traversable
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer

wr :: Int -> Writer (Sum Int, Sum Int) Int
wr 0 = tell (Sum 1, Sum 0) $> f 0
wr 1 = tell (Sum 0, Sum 1) $> g 1
wr n = return $ h n

collect :: [Int] -> ([Int], (Int, Int))
collect = second (getSum *** getSum) . runWriter . traverse wr
```

Summing is a monoid, double summing is a monoid, the `Writer` monad handles monoids, `traverse` maps a list with an effectful function and performs all effects.

This:

```
f = (+ 1)
g = (+ 2)
h = (+ 3)

main = print $ collect [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1]
```

prints `([1,3,5,6,1,1,1,7,3],(4,2))` — four zeros and two ones.